# .htaccess/symfony2 - rewrite-redirect /en/ doesn't match /en

Tags: regex, .htaccess, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have the following code in my .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch permanent /en/(.*) /$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^en/?(.*)?/?$  $1  [R=301,L,QSA]
```

With and/or the RewriteBase /

What i'm trying to do is to redirect every `http://example.com/en/somthing` to `http://example.com/somthing` (be it with the trailing slash or not)

Instead, when I access `http://example.com/en/admin` (without trailing slash) I get redirected to `http://example.com//admin` (with 2 slashes)
When I access `http://example.com/en/admin/` (with the trailing slash) everything works fine..
Every other url works with either the trailing slash and not..
I'm using symfony2 if this helps and this is my routing.yml

```
deo_secure:
    resource: "@DeoSecureBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin

welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }

_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix: /demo

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

The routing file for deo_secure is:

```
deo_secure_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: DeoSecureBundle:Admin:index }
```

Comment: RedirectMatch permanent /en/(.*) $1

Answer (score 0):

You could try This

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/en/(.*) 
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [R=301,L]
```

sample :

http://sepidarcms.ir/en/admin/

redirect to:

http://sepidarcms.ir/admin/

Comment: is the sample based on symfony2?

Comment: I Didn't work with symfony Framework .But It Should Work If Dosn't overlap to other code

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your original directive to this:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/en/(.*)$ /$1
```

or better replace it with:

```
Redirect permanent /en/ /
```